# can we give create function name like my-account in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am working on codeigniter and I want to give function name like edit-profile and controller name like my-account. 
I have tried to create like this but it is giving error.

Comment: You can not use "-" with function name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can

**In Controller**

```
public function my_account($value='')
{
    # code...
}
```

**In Routes**

```
$route['my-account'] = "controller_name/my_account";
```

---

**Tested. Works fine**

[image]

**In config**

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

Comment: i have done exactly as it is but giving page not found

Comment: @yogeshwari happy to help ;)

Answer (score 2):

In config/routes.php

```
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Just change to **TRUE** and you can use either _ or -.

and name functions separated by underscores then when request url use 
separate words with dash

I hope my answer would be useful

Answer (score 0):

i hope you are asking about name conventions just through this url if about method name convention [class and method naming](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html)